# how to build Dapp for Android using react-native

Tags: private-blockchain, metamask, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have a ethereum Dapp for web application and have metamask extension installed in my chrome browser to make transactions. Now i want the same application to be developed in android using react-native.

How to install some wallets like metamask in the devices and make transactions in mobile device without using Mainnet?

Is that possible to achieve this?If yes can any one please help me out on how to develop this app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without using main net ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling with the same exact issue myself. In the past, I've managed to achieve this by creating an instance of web3 on the react-native application. Doing so, I was able to perform and sign transactions locally on the phone, making use of a Keystore file on a static location of the phone. From my experience, this eventually became really slow and react-native+web3js (I followed [this link](https://medium.com/@dxenu/react-native-0-60-4-with-web3-js-1-2-0-8090a1decee2) as a helper if I remember correctly) didn't work 100% well together. So now I'm trying different approaches, like using `webview` tags to make use of a browser inside your react native app. So, if you want, give it a try with the web3+RN, maybe you are luckier than me and it ends up working as expected with you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you want to share your experience after using `webview`? I tried to use `rn-nodeify` with `ipfs` module and there were a few bundle issues which I could not solve. I am looking into options to use `web3` in my RN app. There requires hacks to my understanding so far.